# How to quickly identify a called Javascript function's file

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have problem identifying where this JavaScript function, *myFunction()*, is located? I cannot set a debug point, because it is within a button. Wrap it in an extra function will do, but want to find out a quicker way.

Is there any tool to help? I am using visual studio, and all common web browsers.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="1.js"></script>
...
<script src="n.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I have many javascript files referenced via script tag, looking through it one by one is not what I want.

**I found a solution:** 
that I can search it from Chrome: F12-> Sources tab -> search text field.

Comment: You can search in a bunch of files with Windows or Sublime Text (among a pile of examples I guess)

Comment: My problem is that I don't have javscript files within my local machine. I found a solution. please see my update. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ctrl + shift + f in chrome, and look for myFunction
It can easily find it in any file.

Comment: sorry, you meant open the windows in the middle, and open each file, and  search the function on each file?

Comment: Which is exactly what I was suggesting :) ctrl + shift + f is the shortcut key in the dev tools